# What kind of time series do I need?

Tags: average, time-series

I am trying to optimize a list of websites on which to purchase banner advertising using the following setup:

- For each banner ad impression I buy I am charged $0.001.
- When my ad is clicked it results in $0.50 revenue.
- Each website has a constant but different number of visitors per day.
- You are only allowed to pick the top 10 sites for your campaign.
- You have a fixed budget on which to spend advertising

Initially I approached this problem simply by calculating ROI for each site.  However, my budget was not being spent because the sites it chose did not get enough visitors.

What I really want to calculate for each website is a value of **Profit Per Minute**.  How do I approach this?

Also, this should be a rolling time series as the set of data changes every second.

Thank you.